# Why c++ Stl not using sharing resources of vector to save memory?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

copy of vector must allocate new memory only on attempt to modify it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<char> vec(100 * 1000 * 1024, 3);  // allocating  100*1000*kib,  nice.
   vector<char> array[] = {vec,vec,vec,vec};  // now we using 500*1000*kib, VERY NICE, no more!

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GundolfGundelfinger Write that as an answer with the appropriate cite.

Comment: @GundolfGundelfinger That was even better :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy on Write is not supported by the stl. Strings which did have COW, post C++11 no longer do. COW although attractive as a way to save memory means iterators become useless.

We will need to lock the underlying store on any access. This will need to be a slow atomic check in the event a copy of a container is passed to another thread.